# Total price of items in Cart react

Tags: reactjs, sum

I wanted to get total sum of all items in the cart page based on their qty. Algorithm that i used is incorrect because it is not calculating sum of each item with its qty, but sum of all item price and sum of all item qty. Can anyone help how to calculate each item price with its qty and sum it up with all item prices ? Here is the source code:

```
 let totalQty = 0;
 let totalSum = 0;
 let newArr = [];
    
this.props.cart.map(item => {
        totalQty += item.qty
        item.prices.filter(price => price.currency.symbol === this.props.symbol)
      .map(price => newArr.push(price.amount))
       }) 
    totalSum = newArr.reduce((acc, val)=> (acc + val*totalQty), 0)
    let tax = this.props.formatNumber({ value: totalSum*(21/100), digitCount: 0 })
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push the subtotal for each item into `newArr` instead then sum up at the end

```
let totalQty = 0;
let totalSum = 0;
let newArr = [];
    
this.props.cart.map(item => {
  totalQty += item.qty
  item
    .prices
    .filter(price => price.currency.symbol === this.props.symbol)
    .map(price => newArr.push(item.qty * price.amount))
}) 
totalSum = newArr.reduce((acc, val)=> (acc + val), 0)
let tax = this.props.formatNumber({ value: totalSum*(21/100), digitCount: 0 })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
const totalAmount = this.props.cart.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
   return curr.qty*curr.price + acc
},0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use reduce on totalQty to calculate the count, and reduce totalSum to get qty * amount

```
let totalQty = this.props.cart.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.qty, 0)
let totalSum = this.props.cart.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const price = item.prices.find(price => price.currency.symbol === this.props.symbol)
    if (price) {
        acc += (price.amount * item.qty)
    }
    return acc
}, 0)
```